# Log4Net won't create custom event log in event viewer

Tags: c#, log4net, event-log

My WPF app uses Log4Net to record messages to the event viewer. This is working great on most machines.  However, there are two machines in my office where there are problems.  One is a physical Windows 7 machine with 2 GB of ram, the other is a virtual machine running XP, which also has 2 GB of ram.

The problem is that even though the users are logged in using accounts with administrator rights, the system won't let them create the custom event log that I set up for my application.  This is causing my program to die.

I can add error handling on all of the Log calls, but my feeling on this is I shouldn't.  The messages are being logged in the catch handler for another error that already occurred.  Just what am I going to do with the error information if it can't be logged?

In any event, I tried to create the custom event log on the XP virtual machine yesterday and it still wasn't created.  What exactly do I need to do to get the custom event log created on these two machines?

Tony

Comment: How are you creating the event log on the Windows XP machine? Show some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the problem wasn't in the logging code at all. My program uses WPF for the GUI.  It's start-up sequence does the minimum amount of work on the UI Thread so it can display the UI as soon as possible.

The rest of the initialization is done on a background thread.  I knew that an error was occurring, but I couldn't find the custom error log in the list of logs in the Event Viewer.  It turns out that my code didn't find some data in the database that it needs and was trying to report the error.  This is a 2 step process which involves first recording the error to the log and then displaying a custom `MessageBox` dialog.  I was getting a `XamlParseException` when the program was trying to display this dialog.

To make a long story short, the problem that was crashing the program was the `XamlParseException`.  This was thrown because I was calling the custom `MessageBox's` `Show` method on the background thread, not on the UI thread.  Because I couldn't find the custom event source in the event viewer, I couldn't find the error, so I assumed that the error was a permisions issue.

By the way, I did try to create the event log manually at one point, and yesterday I checked the registry and did find the entry for the custom event source.

There is one other machine here that is having the same problem.  I'm sure it's the same exact issue.  I'm adding logic to the error handling to make sure that the custom `MessageBox` is always called on the UI Thread so the program won't bomb like that if the same issue recurs.

Answer (score 0):

We would need to see how you tried creating the event log on the XP machine...

Generally, you need to read this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/49dwckkz(v=vs.80).aspx

Particularly the note discussing when to create your custom event log:

*"In general, create the new event source during the installation of your application. This allows time for the operating system to refresh its list of registered event sources and their configuration. If the operating system has not refreshed its list of event sources and you attempt to write an event with the new source, the write operation will fail. If creating the source during installation is not an option, then try to create the source well ahead of the first write operation, perhaps during your application initialization. If you choose this approach, be sure your initialization code is running with administrator rights on the computer. These rights are required for creating new event sources."*

Try creating the custom log in advance of the first logging event to use it.